# Drawing colored boxes around chpater numbers in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, books

How can I get the following formatting style for my TOC using the book class and (possibly) the tocloft (or titletoc) package? What I want is the small colored rectangles around the chapter numbers.
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a compilable code to play with, so we don't have to type everything? It certainly can be done with `titletoc`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F0C000}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{%
    \rlap{\color{myyellow}\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\cftchapnumwidth}{\dp\strutbox+\ht\strutbox+0.4ex}}%
    \hbox to \cftchapnumwidth\bgroup\color{white}\hss}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{\hss\egroup}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\hskip0.3em\relax}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\section{Foo section}
\lipsum

\section{Foo section}
\lipsum

\chapter{Bar}

\section{Bar section}
\lipsum

\section{Bar section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

We change the number part of the chapter entries via `\cftchappresnum` and `\cftchapaftersnum` to

1. insert a yellow bar of the width of `\cftchapnumwidth` and appropriate height/depth that doesn't have any width being taken into account (`\rlap`), and
2. span a new box around the chapter number, also of width `\cftchapnumwidth`, that centers its content within the box.

Additionally, a small gap after the box is added via `\cftchapaftersnumb`.

[image: Table of contents with colored number]

Comment: Is it also possible to do it using titletoc and tikz? A solution with that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using `titletoc` for this seems to be a bit more complicated. I can't see a way to just change the label format without redeclaring the whole chapter entry line format. So a solution would depend on the default format of the used document class.

Comment: How can one add a colored box (different color) arount the chapter titles?